# Django Form Validation Error Displaying Django Debug Page

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, exception

I have a signup view which takes an email, password, confirm password, and extra string, which must be unique. All of my validation errors return properly (e.g. if an email is duplicated, it displays this must be unique, and if the passwords don't match is displays passwords don't match). However, the extra string displays the django debug page with the validation error, rather than displaying it to the form. Why is this happening?

Django debug page error:

```
ValidationError at /signup/
['Extra string must be unique.']
```

Excerpt of template:

```
                    {% for field in form %}
                        <div class="form-group">

                            {% for error in field.errors %}
                                <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
                            {% endfor %}
                            <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}:</label>
                            {{ field }}

                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
```

Form:

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    email = forms.CharField(label='Email', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    extra_string = forms.CharField(label='Extra String (Must be unique)', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        """A function to check that the two passwords provided by the user match."""
        # Check that the two password entries match
        #: User's password.
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        #: Password confirm.
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The passwords must match.") #: This displays properly
        return password2
    def ensure_unique_string(self):
        """Checks that the entered extra string is unique"""

        extra= self.cleaned_data.get("extra_string")
        if len(ExtraString.objects.filter(name=extra)) > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Ana Group Name must be unique.") #: This displays django debug page
        return extra
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.clean_password2())
        user.extra_string = self.ensure_unique_string()
        user.has_migrated_pwd = True
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Signup View:

```
class SignUpView(View):
    template_name = "account/signup.html"

    def get(self, request):
        form = UserCreationForm()
        return render(request=request, template_name=self.template_name, context={
            "form": form
        })

    def post(self, request):
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully Registered')
            next_url = request.POST.get('next') if 'next' in request.POST else 'profile'
            return redirect(next_url)

        return render(request, template_name=self.template_name, context={"form": form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that because you raise in save methods, when you are in the save, is telling your all field are validate, so you need to validate your field before call save methods.

you have 2 solution:

in clean_FIELD_NAME:

```
   def clean_extra_string(self, data):
        if len(ExtraString.objects.filter(name=data)) > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Ana Group Name must be unique.")
        return data
```

in validate methods:

```
 def validate(self, validate_data):
        if len(ExtraString.objects.filter(name=validate_data['extra'])) > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Ana Group Name must be unique.")

    return validate_data
```